# Printing file output to printer?

Tags: php

I am trying to generate some contents dynamically from a PHP page for print. Currently, I am using a file to store contents and then send that file to the printer. Is there a way, I can store contents in a variable or buffer and send to printer directly with out saving them in the file.

My current code:

```
ob_start();
include 'printcheck.php';
$result = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('/var/www/prints/rt/rtorder.txt', ob_get_contents());
// end buffering and displaying page
ob_end_flush();
```

Print it.

```
exec("cat "/var/www/prints/rt/rtorder.txt" | lp -d "TSP100");
```

Comment: use `session` array if convenient

Comment: Investigate [`popen()`](http://php.net/popen) instead of `file_put_contents` to send the output via pipe to `lp` directly.

Comment: @mario has the solution - was gonna say this too. In most unixy type systems devices like printers or your audio speakers and such are represented by "files" (not really, but good enough for this) which you can pipe data to directly. For example, you can "sudo cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio" to hear noise.